# Why use seq 0 in bash for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop

Why use  seq 0 in bash for loop?

```
for i in `seq 0 $(( ${#ARRAYEX[@]} - 1 ))`
do
    echo "ARRAYEX${i}=${ARRAYEX[${i}]}"
done
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`seq`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/seq) command generates a sequence of numbers.

For example

```
seq 0 10
```

generates a sequence of numbers from 0 up to 10:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

<sup>(usually each number is on a new line, but I place them after each other)</sup>

In your example a sequence on number starting at 0 up to the size of the array minus 1 is generated.
The `seq 0 $(( ${#ARRAYEX[@]} - 1 ))` part expands to:

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

assuming that the ARRAYEX has a size of 5.

Inside the loop the array is used again, so the loop is iterating over all array element (as the first element of the array starts at 0).

Answer (score 2):

`seq 0 $(( ${#ARRAYEX[@]} - 1 ))` creates a sequence of all the possible indexes of the array. You can also use

```
for ((i=0; i<${#ARRAYEX[@]}; ++i )) ; do
```